# Is it possible for lcg_value() to roll a perfect 1?

Tags: php

Title says it all. The documentation isn't clear if [`lcg_value`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.lcg-value.php) picks a number `[0,1]` or `[0,1)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. [Test shows](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/tests/math/lcg_value_basic.phpt) that 0 and 1 is legit values. But...
2. [PHP](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/lcg.c#L55) uses [Combined Linear Congruential Generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combined_Linear_Congruential_Generator). Like wiki says `R` value cannot be equal to `0` (because of checking for that) and cannot be equal to `1` (because `X` less than `m`(because X result of modulus `m - 1`))

So, result of `lcg_value` belongs to (0,1) not to [0,1]